# ASP.Net MVC Passing array value to database table columns

Tags: sql, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I used the code from http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/net-mvc-upload-a-csv-file-to-database-with-bulk-upload/#comment-188 to upload, read and insert to DB the csv file. My problem now is how can I pass the values from the csv file to the specific database table columns.

```
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        string line = string.Empty;
        string[] strArray;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;

        Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

        line = sr.ReadLine();
        strArray = r.Split(line);

        Array.ForEach(strArray, s => dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()));

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();

            row.ItemArray = r.Split(line);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

and ...

```
    private static String ProcessBulkCopy(DataTable dt)
    {
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        string connString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using(  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {

                    conn.Open();

                    copy.DestinationTableName = "BulkImportDetails";
                    copy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                    try
                    {
                        copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                        Feedback = "Upload complete";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Feedback = ex.Message;
                    }
            }
        }

        return Feedback;
   }
```

Below are my sample contents:

08/01/12,05:20:12 AM,243752,,South Lobby3,522557,IN

08/01/12,05:26:03 AM,188816,,North Lobby1,358711,IN

My DB table columns:

empno | date | time

I only need to insert the first three arrays.. (e.g. 08/01/12,05:20:12 AM,243752) and proceed to the next row to insert it again to its specified columns. My csv file doesn't have headers. I saw a code about passing the array values but it requires headers. How can I pass the values even without having a header in my csv file? Please help me guys.. Thank you..